# Why does QFileDialog.getOpenFileName ignore the dir argument on Fedora?

Tags: python, qt, fedora, gnome

I used to be able to set an initial directory for the native open-file dialog in PyQt5, PyQt6, PySide2 etc. using code like this:

```py
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
    self,
    'Open file',
    '/home/michael/last_path',
)
```

where the 3d argument is a `str` specifying the initial directory for the dialog.

On recent versions of Fedora (running either wayland or X11), the directory argument is silently ignored.

Strangely, it does still work for `getSaveFileName`.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on? Or where I could report this? (Qt? Fedora devs?) Or similarly, where I could look to start fixing this myself?

---

Update with more version info:

Currently on Fedora 37 with Gnome 43.3, but problem has been around for a while now, going back to Fedora 33 at least, if I remember correctly. Same problem on two different machines. Also seen it in software not written by me but also using Python & Qt (e.g. Veusz).

Thought at first it was a Wayland thing, but checked after comment below from @relent95 and actually happens on X11 too.

---

I've now confirmed that it works when I install PyQt5 or PyQt6 into a virtualenv with `pip`, but fails when I use the `dnf` installed PyQt5 or PyQt6. So possibly a fedora packaging issue?

Comment: Post enough debugging details, such as versions of Fedora, Gtk, etc. In my Fedora 35, it works fine. Anyway I guess you have mistaken, because there's no special logic for setting an initial directory that depends on Wayland in the GtkFileChooserWidget.

Comment: It says "initial directory", but on windows its actually initial file path, dont know if it's relevant to linux, though, try setting file path and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a bug in packaged PyQt from Fedora 32 onwards, but fixed in 39.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2258467

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you described might be related to a known issue in Qt, the framework used by the QFileDialog class. Qt uses a platform plugin to interact with the underlying operating system, and this plugin might not work correctly on some systems or configurations.

In the case of GNOME with Wayland, the problem might be related to the fact that Wayland uses a different protocol than X11 for communicating between applications and the display server. This can cause compatibility issues with Qt and other applications that rely on X11.

### ** 1rst way -** use `zenity` or `kdialog`

To use `zenity` or `kdialog` as a fallback: `zenity` and `kdialog` are command-line utilities for creating dialog boxes in GNOME and KDE, respectively. We can use these utilities as a fallback if the QFileDialog doesn't behave correctly. Here's an example:

```
import os, subprocess, platform
# pip install -U zenite

def get_open_file_name():
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
        if os.environ.get('WAYLAND_DISPLAY'):
            # Fallback to zenity or kdialog
            if subprocess.call(['which', 'zenity']) == 0:
                command = ['zenity', '--file-selection']
            elif subprocess.call(['which', 'kdialog']) == 0:
                command = ['kdialog', '--getopenfilename']
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Neither zenity nor kdialog found')
            result = subprocess.check_output(command)
            return result.decode().strip()
    # Fallback to QFileDialog
    return QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open file")[0]
```

This function checks if the user is running a Linux system with the Wayland display server. If so, it checks if the `zenity` or `kdialog` command-line utilities are available. If they are, it runs the appropriate command to display the file dialog and returns the selected file path. If neither utility is available, it raises a RuntimeError. If the user is not running a Linux system with the Wayland display server, or if the file dialog fails for any reason, it falls back to using QFileDialog.

### ** 2nd way -** `QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView`

Use `QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage` to display a custom file dialog: `QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage` provides a way to display a custom HTML page in a `QWebEngineView` widget. We can use this to display a custom file dialog that allows us to set the initial directory. Here's an example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtCore

class CustomFileDialog(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self._current_dir = None
        
        self.setHtml("""
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Custom File Dialog</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <input type="file" id="file" webkitdirectory directory />
            </body>
        </html>
        """)
        
        self.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(self._on_download_requested)
        
    def set_current_directory(self, directory):
        self._current_dir = directory
        
    def _on_download_requested(self, download):
        download.setDirectory(self._current_dir)
```

This code defines a CustomFileDialog class that inherits from QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView. It sets the HTML content of the view to a simple file dialog with an "Open directory" button. When the user clicks this button, it opens the native file dialog with the directory flag set, allowing the user to select a directory. Once the user selects a directory, the downloadRequested signal is emitted by the QWebEngineProfile, and the _on_download_requested method sets the initial directory for the file dialog to the directory selected by the user.

You can use this CustomFileDialog class like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # INJECT IT HERE 
        self._file_dialog = CustomFileDialog(self)
        self._file_dialog.set_current_directory('/home/user/') #  It sets the initial directory for the file dialog to '/home/user/'
        self._file_dialog.page().setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self._file_dialog)
```

### ** 3rd way -** `xdg-desktop-portal`

`xdg-desktop-portal` is a portal that allows applications to show native file dialogs on desktop environments like GNOME. We can use the `xdg-desktop-portal` Python library to show the file dialog using xdg-desktop-portal. Here's an example:

```
import xdg.DesktopEntry
import xdg.DesktopEntry.Parser
import xdg.DesktopEntry.TrustLevel
import xdg.IconTheme
import xdg.Mime

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gio', '2.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Gio

def show_file_dialog(title, initial_directory):
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserNative.new(title, None, Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN, None, None)
    dialog.set_current_folder(initial_directory)
    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = dialog.get_filename()
        dialog.destroy()
        return filename
    else:
        dialog.destroy()
        return None

def set_initial_directory(dialog, directory):
    app_id = xdg.DesktopEntry.get_('xdg-screensaver').get_filename()
    portal = Gio.DBusProxy.new_for_bus_sync(Gio.BusType.SYSTEM, Gio.DBusProxyFlags.NONE, None, 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop', '/org/freedesktop/portal/desktop', 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop', None)
    options = Gio.Variant('a{sv}', {
        'current_folder': directory,
        'title': dialog.windowTitle(),
        'parent_window': int(dialog.winId()),
        'accept_label': 'Open',
        'cancel_label': 'Cancel',
        'modal': True,
        'finish_on_close': True,
        'filters': [],
        'extra': Gio.Variant('a{sv}', {
            'show_hidden': True
        })
    })
    portal.OpenFileChooser(options, 'unix:fd:3', app_id)

def on_file_dialog_response(dialog, response):
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = dialog.get_filename()
        print(f'Selected file: {filename}')
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        print('Dialog cancelled')
    dialog.destroy()

def show_file_dialog_with_portal(title, initial_directory):
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title,
        None,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
        (
            Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
            Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OPEN,
            Gtk.ResponseType.OK
        )
    )
    dialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    dialog.set_current_folder(initial_directory)
    dialog.connect('response', on_file_dialog_response)
    set_initial_directory(dialog, initial_directory)

show_file_dialog_with_portal('Open file', '/home/michael/last_path')
```

`set_initial_directory` function sets the initial directory for the file dialog, and the `show_file_dialog_with_portal` function shows the file dialog using `xdg-desktop-portal`. This method allows you to use the native file dialog in GNOME

### **4th way -** `QPlatformFileDialogHelper`

Use QPlatformFileDialogHelper: QPlatformFileDialogHelper is a low-level class in Qt that provides a way to implement custom file dialog behavior on different platforms. You can use it to create a custom file dialog implementation that works correctly on GNOME with Wayland. Here's an example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPlatformFileDialogHelper, QFileDialog

class MyFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        if self.testOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog):
            self._helper = QPlatformFileDialogHelper()
            self._helper.setDirectory('/home/Niceman/last_path')

    def showEvent(self, event): #important!
        super().showEvent(event)
        if not self.testOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog):
            self._helper.setDirectory('/home/michael/last_path')
```

In this example, i  custom file dialog class that uses QPlatformFileDialogHelper to set the initial directory. If the `DontUseNativeDialog` option is set, we create a new instance of `QPlatformFileDialogHelper` and set the initial directory. Otherwise, we set the initial directory in the existing instance of `QPlatformFileDialogHelper`.

### **5th way - ** Qt QML FileDialog

Use the Qt QML FileDialog component: The Qt QML FileDialog component provides a platform-independent file dialog that you can use in your Python application using PyQt or PySide. Here's an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Open file"
    folder: "/home/michael/last_path"
    onAccepted: {
        // Do something with the selected file
        console.log("Selected file:", fileUrl)
    }
    onRejected: {
        // The user canceled the file dialog or selected a directory
        console.log("File dialog canceled or directory selected")
    }
}
```

This QML code defines a FileDialog component that you can use in your PyQt or PySide application. It sets the initial directory of the file dialog to /home/michael/last_path. When the user selects a file, the onAccepted signal is emitted with the URL of the selected file. When the user cancels the file dialog or selects a directory, the onRejected signal is emitted.

Embed the QML file dialog in a PyQt or PySide application: You can embed the QML file dialog in your PyQt or PySide application using the QQuickWidget class. Here's an example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQuickWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Load the QML file dialog component
        self.file_dialog = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget()
        self.file_dialog.setResizeMode(QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)
        self.file_dialog.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('file_dialog.qml'))
        
        # Add the QML file dialog component to the main window
        self.setCentralWidget(self.file_dialog)
        
        # Connect the signals of the QML file dialog component to Python slots
        self.file_dialog.rootObject().accepted.connect(self.handle_accepted)
        self.file_dialog.rootObject().rejected.connect(self.handle_rejected)
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QUrl)
    def handle_accepted(self, file_url):
        # Do something with the selected file
        print(f"Selected file: {file_url.toLocalFile()}")
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_rejected(self):
        # The user canceled the file dialog or selected a directory
        print("File dialog canceled or directory selected")
```

This code defines a MainWindow class that loads the QML file dialog component and adds it to the main window using a QQuickWidget. It also connects the signals of the QML file dialog component to Python slots that handle the selected file URL or the file dialog rejection

Comment: Thanks @MessMan. So do you think this is a Qt issue that I should support to Qt (not e.g. PyQt) developers?